# Erro ao realizar login usando Facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, oauth2, owin

Tentando realizar login através do facebook me deparo, com o seguinte erro:

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
>   Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
>   Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da
>   atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter
>   mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código. 
>   Detalhes da Exceção: System.NullReferenceException: Referência de
>   objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
>   Linha 329: Linha 330:            // Sign in the user with this
>   external login provider if the user already has a login Linha 331:
>   var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo,
>   isPersistent: false); Linha 332:            switch (result) Linha 333:
>   {
>
> [NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para uma
>   instância de um objeto.]
>   EuVotoAf.Controllers.d__26.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Users\Renan\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\EuVotoAf\EuVotoAf\Controllers\AccountController.cs:331
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +97
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +17
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +26    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9765121    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

*Debugando* a aplicação, reparei que o erro está na seguinte linha:

```
var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
```

E entrando um pouco mais, no meu construtor da classe `ApplicationSignInManager`
no *return*  da linha:

```
 return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
```

Fica setado como **Null**. Um detalhe que talvez possa ser importante, é que estou customizando o `identity`, para usar o `Guid` como chave primaria, ao invés do padrão `String`.

Coloquei as classes `IdentityConfig` e `Start.Auth` no [gist](https://gist.github.com/Renancp01/37630bcf4f05672f9ef7de3daf7fda4d) para um detalhamento maior.

Como resolvo isso  ?

Comment: Faltou a parte principal do erro: o *stack trace*

Comment: Então **`HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>()`** está retornando `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja o método **`ConfigureAuth()`** na classe **`Startup`**, nele tem a seguinte linha comentada `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);`.

Perceba que o erro que você está recebendo é que a linha `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();` está retornando `null`.

Basicamente, é  o seguinte: toda e qualquer requisição vai criar uma instância de `ApplicationDbContext` e `ApplicationUserManager` e vai disponibilizá-las para uso.

O erro acontece porque você está tentando capturar **`ApplicationSignInManager`**, mas ele não foi criado. Então, descomente a terceira e tudo deve funcionar.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create); //Esta linha estava comentada

   // ...
}
```